# Завершить AsyncTask по нажатию кнопки "назад"

Tags: android, java

Добрый день. Помогите корректно прервать асинхронную задачу по нажатию "назад". В данный момент логика следующая в приложении.

1. Из главной OnCreate вызывается наследованный от AsyncTask UpdateTask.
2. В doInBackground создается экземпляр JSONParser и у него вызывается метод, создающий экземпляр DefaultHttpClient и запускающий его на выполнение (во время которого качается длинная json строка).

То есть асинхронная загрузка внутри асинхронной задачи. Вопрос:

1. Как обнаружить нажатую кнопку "назад"?
2. Как прервать загрузку?

Я понял, что если в doInBackground выполняется цикл, то при желании можно проверять на каждой итерации прервана ли задача, что-то вроде:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    if (isCancelled()) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cancelled");
      return null;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

...

```
//где-то в программе
if(*нажата клавиша "назад"*)
  mt.cancel(false)
```

Но как я вклинюсь в задачу загрузки данных? А то у меня на данный момент, если во время загрузки выйти из приложения (назад или home), то через какое-то время выходит сообщение об ошибке (загрузка продолжается в фоне и не корректно реагирует по окончанию).

Comment: Решение в лоб: в onPostExecute чекать контекст, если null, значит приложение закрыто/свёрнуто, тогда ничего не делаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, можно поразмышлять:

1) Как я уже сказал, решение в лоб: в onPostExecute чекать контекст, если null, значит приложение закрыто/свёрнуто, тогда ничего не делаем. Независимо от того, что вы ещё сделаете, эта проверка в любом случае нужна.

2) Если у вас там `HttpClient`, то запрос можно отменить:

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Логика:

а) В AssyncTask объявить `public` метод для отмены запроса.

б) В Activity отлавливать нажатия. Если кнопка Back нажата, то вызывать public метод тот и закрывать соединение `httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()`

Comment: @Suvitruf, хм. Можно в Activity поди на onPause() воткнуть прерывание загрузки тогда. Сейчас код такой:

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        updateTask.cancelRequest();
    }

... в свою очередь в UpdateTask

    public void cancelRequest(){
        jParser.cancelRequest();
    }

... в свою очередь в JSONParser

    public void cancelRequest(){
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

Загрузка отменяется. Но как проверить идет ли она сейчас, на случай, если прерывать не надо ибо нечего, и для корректного восстановления.

Comment: @Saint или самому всю эту логику писать, или использовать что-то вроде Volley.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask.cancel()` сам по себе ничего не отменяет - он просто выставляет флаг: `cancel`, `не cancel`. Дальше уже проблема разработчика правильно проверить этот флаг и правильно завершить задачу.

В данном случае, я бы написал отдельный синхронизированный метод завершения `AsyncTask`, в котором корректно закрывается сокет/коннект, парсер Json и проч. дела. То есть в общем примерно то что описал [@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf), но только обрамленный `synchronized`